# Debugging gcroot in c++/cli

Tags: .net, visual-studio, c++-cli

How to watch the object, referenced by an `gcroot` in c++/cli, while debugging in Visual Studio?
Visual Studio only shows gcroots' handle value in debug watches.

Answer (score 1):

1. Save handle value of a gcroot, shown by a debug watch.
2. Add a debug watch :
   `System.Runtime.InteropServices.GCHandle.FromIntPtr ( (IntPtr)0x0000000025eaf1d8).Target`. Where 0x0000000025eaf1d8 - value from 1.
3. Switch to any managed frame to toggle the debug watch to Managed mode: go to call stack window and double click such frame.
   The watch should now show the object.